# Can I get r, g and b from fillStyle of my canvas?

Tags: javascript, html

It is possible to get rgb color from context.fillStyle (and put 'red', 'green' and 'blue' to variables)?
How?

Comment: The context fill style could also include an alpha, or it could be a gradient. Why are you trying to read it? For save/restore there are specific `.save()` and `.restore()` calls.

Comment: You've got two answers now.  Are either of them helpful?  If so, accept one.  If not, please add an update to your question or a comment saying why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When set with a simple HTML hexadecimal color value, the fillStyle property exposes a string of the form: #RRGGBB.  You can extract the colors like so:

```
var r = parseInt(context.fillStyle.substring(1,3), 16);
var g = parseInt(context.fillStyle.substring(3,5), 16);
var b = parseInt(context.fillStyle.substring(5), 16);
```

The colors values have the range 0 to 255.

If you've set a colour value with alpha (such as "rgba(127, 63, 255, 0.5)") they are returned like that and you'll have to do a bit more work.